# Incorrect tableView row is deleted when deleting tableView rows in ascending order (bottom to top)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delete-row

When deleting tableView rows in ascending order (bottom to top), the incorrect row above the selected row is being deleted. For example, with the following four rows:

A
B
C
D

when swiping left to delete row D, row C is being deleted.

Inversely, when deleting in a descending order (top to bottom) there is no problem whatsoever, the rows are being deleted in their proper order. The basic deletion code follows with the tableView having two sections (the problem occurs when deleting in an ascending order in both sections). Any suggestions, much appreciated!

```
let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: NSLocalizedString("Delete", comment:"Delete")) { _, _, complete in
            let section = indexPath.section
            let row = indexPath.row
            let i = IndexPath(item: row, section: section)
           
            if section == 0 {
            
            self.cyclesteps.remove(at: row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [i], with: .automatic)
       
          
                
                let thesample = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceCycling)
                let thepredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: HKSource.default())
                healthStore.deleteSamplesOfType(thesample!, predicate: thepredicate, withCompletion: { (success, count, error) -> Void in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                       
                        if error == nil
                        {
                            // saved successfully
                           
                            //self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [i], with: .automatic)
                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print("Error occured while saving to Health Kit: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                            
                            
                        }
                    })
               })
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended to first delete the item in the database, then in the data source (on success) and then update the view

```
let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: NSLocalizedString("Delete", comment:"Delete")) { _, _, complete in
    
    guard indexPath.section == 0 else { complete(false) }
    let thesample = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceCycling)
    let thepredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: HKSource.default())
    healthStore.deleteSamplesOfType(thesample!, predicate: thepredicate, withCompletion: { (success, count, error) -> Void in
       DispatchQueue.main.async { 
               
           if let error = error {
                print("Error occured while saving to Health Kit: \(error.localizedDescription)")  
                complete(false)                          
           } else {
                // saved successfully
                   
                self.cyclesteps.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                complete(true)
           }
       }
   })                
}
```

And don't forget to call the `complete` handler of the action.

Comment: Tested the revised code (many thanks for the detailed code feedback), but still the same issue occurrs when deleting tableview rows from the bottom up in ascending order, the selected row is not deleted and instead the row immediately above the selection is deleted.

Comment: Then there might be something wrong with your data source. The code is supposed to work.